# CSS 100% will not resize below 1000px

Tags: css, width

I'm working on a custom stylesheet to override this site. https://adminluonline.blackboard.com/. Essentially we want the page elements to load as 100%. They all seem to assume that 1000px is the min-width for some reason. They'll stretch out past that as far as I want but won't go smaller.

I'm using the stylish Firefox plugin and am using `!important` to override. I've even gone as far as telling everything but 1 `div` not to display. However even with just one `div`, with no padding and no margins, it won't cooperate. Does anyone have any suggestions as o what could be my next steps?

Comment: Depends what you want to do with it. Blackboard is FAR more complex to manage and install.

Comment: Solved my own problem. System was loading extra styelsheet that set min-width for html to 1000px.

Answer (score 0):

`#loginpane` has a fixed width of `800px`. That's what's causing the page to stop shrinking. Either use media queries or change this and the child elements which have a static width of 600px
Line 3 of theme1.css:
`body{ min-width: 1000px; }`

Probably the problem.

Comment: even if I set * {width: 100% !IMPORTANT; padding: 0px !IMPORTANT; margin: 0px !IMPORTANT; } which obviously applies to far more than I would want the content is restrict to a minimum width of 1000px;

Comment: I didn't realised the link you provided didn't include anything you'd tried. I've updated my answer.